# Select the same item several times in the knapsack problem [pulp]

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm doing a coursera' [discrete optimization course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/basic-modeling)
which, in the course a tool called Minizinc is used to solve the problems.

I want to translate class examples to python, starting for this one:

[image]
I'm using this example code  reproduce the results:

```
v = {'hammer':6, 'wrench':10, 'screwdriver':8, 'towel':40}
w = {'hammer':13, 'wrench':21, 'screwdriver':17, 'towel':100}
q = {'hammer':1000, 'wrench':400, 'screwdriver':500, 'towel':150}
limit = 1000
items = list(sorted(v.keys()))

# Create model
m = LpProblem("Knapsack", LpMaximize)

# Variables
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', items, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

# Objective
m += sum(v[i]*x[i] for i in items)

# Constraint
m += sum(w[i]*x[i] for i in items) <= limit


# Optimize
m.solve()

# Print the status of the solved LP
print("Status = %s" % LpStatus[m.status])

# Print the value of the variables at the optimum
for i in items:
    print("%s = %f" % (x[i].name, x[i].varValue))

# Print the value of the objective
print("Objective = %f" % value(m.objective))
```

But this is giving a wrong answer since is only taken one of a kind.
How can I add the amount available for each item (dict q) into the constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two very small changes to your code. Firstly you need to remove the upper bound you have set on your `x` variables. At the moments you have binary variables `x[i]` which can be only one or zero.

Secondly you need to add in the constraints which effectively set a custom upper bound for each of the items. Working code and resulting solution below - as you can see multiple wrenches (the highest `v/w` ratio) are chosen, with a single hammer to fill up the small amount of space left.

```
from pulp import *
v = {'hammer':6, 'wrench':10, 'screwdriver':8, 'towel':40}
w = {'hammer':13, 'wrench':21, 'screwdriver':17, 'towel':100}
q = {'hammer':1000, 'wrench':400, 'screwdriver':500, 'towel':150}
limit = 1000
items = list(sorted(v.keys()))

# Create model
m = LpProblem("Knapsack", LpMaximize)

# Variables
x = LpVariable.dicts('x', items, lowBound=0, cat=LpInteger)

# Objective
m += sum(v[i]*x[i] for i in items)

# Constraint
m += sum(w[i]*x[i] for i in items) <= limit

# Quantity of each constraint:
for i in items:
    m += x[i] <= q[i]


# Optimize
m.solve()

# Print the status of the solved LP
print("Status = %s" % LpStatus[m.status])

# Print the value of the variables at the optimum
for i in items:
    print("%s = %f" % (x[i].name, x[i].varValue))

# Print the value of the objective
print("Objective = %f" % value(m.objective))
print("Total weight = %f" % sum([x[i].varValue*w[i] for i in items]))
```

Which returns:

Status = Optimal

```
x_hammer = 1.000000
x_screwdriver = 0.000000
x_towel = 0.000000
x_wrench = 47.000000
Objective = 476.000000
Total weight = 1000.000000
```